# Is a solid torus contractible or homotopic equivalent to S^1

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to figure out if the solid torus ($D^2 \times S^1$) is contractible, homotopic equivalent to $S^1$, or neither?

I know that $S^1$ is not contractible, but since its part of a product space, does that matter?

Comment: $D^2$ is contractible.

Comment: what happens if you contract each disk to a point?

Comment: I see, so the whole solid torus is not contractible but it is homotopic equivalent to $S^1$, right?

Comment: @noobisko That's exactly right.

Comment: But the solid torus has its center circle as a deformation retract of the entire solid torus.